# Am I "Doing it Wrong" by using the star to mark questions that I want to review later?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

In the whole 13 days since I became a member I've been using the Star to mark a question for my own review later (since there's a spot for it on my profile).

My reason for doing this is that I read through the site on my phone quite a bit, but I don't like doing markup on my phone.

Today, it occurred to me that I might be messing with someone's score, other parts of the ratings and reputation that I don't know about, etc.

Is this something I should stop doing? Is there a better way to do this? Should this be a feature "Mark for review later"?

As I stated in the first sentence, I'm a NOOB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you are not doing it wrong.

By clicking the star you are marking it as a favourite, which as you pointed out pops them in to the `Favorites` tab in your profile making it easy for you to find them.

You will receive notifications of any edits, new answers, comments & edits to answers.

Marking questions as favourites does not affect the reputation of any user.

There are two badges that are awarded to users who ask a question that has been marked as a favourite. They are:

[Favorite Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/33/favorite-question) - Question favorited by 25 users. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

[Stellar Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/36/stellar-question) - Question favorited by 100 users. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

So in short, carry on as you are!

Don't forget, that you can search the official FAQ by visiting http://meta.stackexchange.com and [searching the FAQ tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).